# How to not have the screen scroll down to show the first item in a flatlist with an inverted flatlist React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have an inverted flatlist to show a news feed, but the most recent news item is the last item in the data object to the flatlist, hence why I am using an inverted flatlist. But an inverted flatlist pushes the screen down when it is first rendered to be able to see the first item (last on the page) at the bottom. I want to have the last item in the data (the most recent piece of news) at the top of the page when it is initially rendered. How can I resolve this?

```
<FlatList
                data={Object.values(dataObject)}
                renderItem={({ item }) => <NewsWidget article={item} />}
                contentContainerStyle={styles.body}
                ListFooterComponent={<View style={{ height: 5 }} />}
                inverted
            />
```

This attachment is what is initially rendered. As you can see, there is more news (the most recent) if you were to scroll up. That is what I want to see first at the top.

I tried setting the `initialScrollIndex={0}`, but this did not seem to do anything. I want to see the most recent news at the top, and not have the page scrolled down to see the last piece of news at the bottom.

Comment: Shouldn't the initial scroll index be the last index and not the first? Have you tried `initialScrollIndex={Object.values(dataObject).length - 1}`?

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't seem to work. When making a new post, there are more issues that arise.